# Google Maps: Saving markers to text file/other?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm making an application where the user can create a set of markers and then have the option to export them in some sort of file, so that not only can the map (with the markers) can be saved and reopened, other people using the app can import this file into their application.

At the moment, every time I create a marker, I add the marker object to an arrayList. Here is the code for that:

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
                .title(title)
                .snippet(snippet)
                .draggable(true));
        markers.add(m);
```

This seems to work reasonably well; I am able to get the properties of each marker through methods such as `getTitle()` or `getSnippet()` etc.

However, everytime the activity is destroyed, this contents of this  arrayList disappears as well, thus I feel as though I need to save this information is some file. Here are my questions:

1. Is saving **objects** in a text **file** a good idea? Or should I save strings and integers (only the info i need, rather than the whole marker) and use something else instead of textfiles (sharedprefences maybe?)?
2. How would I be able to do this? Examples for the export and import functions of all the markers would be really helpful.
3. Whenever I rotate the device, the activity is destroyed, thus all the info is gone. Will i have to export and import everytime this happens?

Any help or insight to **any of these questions** would help a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use content provider for sharing data between app.
see this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

for avoiding to refresh after screen rotation add  this line to your manifest file

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: thanks, will take a look at that site in a bit. i have tried to edit the manifest file, however it still restarts.... where exactly do i put that line?